# Appending API response to HTML page -- Disappearing

Tags: javascript, html

For an assignment, I am making a request to the Github Gist API and then appending the response to an HTML page. I am then supposed to allow the user to "favorite" one of the GISTS and then that GIST is to appear in a separate favorites section (favorited GISTS are to be stored in local storage). I am able to make the request, append the information and make the favorited GISTs appear in another section HOWEVER, the lists only appear for a moment and then disappear after I click on the favorite button. I can see the list flash and then go away. All of the other (non-favorite) GIST info also disappears even though it's not supposed. Can anyone please point me in the right direction? I'm not allowed to use any JQuery. Full code here: http://pastebin.com/ic0juq9n

Critical code below:
    var getData = function(url)
    {
    if(!req)
    {
        throw 'Unable to create HttpRequest.';
    }

```
req.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if(this.readyState === 4)
    {
        if (req.status === 200)
        {
            console.log("It worked!!");
            var info = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
            for(var key in info)
            {
                GistList.push(info[key]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("It messed up again");
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < GistList.length; i++)
    {
        generateGistList(GistList[i]);
    }
}

req.open('GET', url);
req.send();

};

  function generateGistList(Gist) {

    var itemList = document.createElement('li');
    var holdURL = document.createElement('div');
    var holdID = document.createElement('div');
    var description = document.createElement('div');
    if (Gist.description === null)
    {
        description.innerHTML = "No description found";
    }
    else
    {
        description.innerHTML = "Description: " + Gist.description;
    }

    holdURL.innerHTML = "URL: " + Gist.url;
    holdID.innerHTML = "ID: " + Gist.id;
    itemList.appendChild(holdID);
    itemList.appendChild(holdURL);
    itemList.appendChild(description);
    ul.appendChild(itemList);
    list.appendChild(ul);

    var favorite = document.createElement("button");
    favorite.innerHTML = "+";
    favorite.setAttribute("gistId", Gist.id);
    itemList.appendChild(favorite);
    favorite.onclick = function()
    {
        var gistId = this.getAttribute("gistId"); //saved   
        var toBeFavoredGist = findById(gistId);

        //here you add the gist to your favorite list in the localStorage   
        and remove it from the gist list and add it to favorite list
        addFavorite(toBeFavoredGist);
        DisplayFavs();
        //removeGist(toBeFavoredGist);
     }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure if you're using forms that the form tag has an action attribute!